# Stuck with Flexslider - Not showing

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm working on a school project and I'm struggling to get this flexslider to show

http://lauralynn87.github.io/WSP/Project/

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can please help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bunch of javascript errors, basically it can't find the js to include.  Make a habit of looking at the developer tools and your life will be much easier.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery.flexslider.js, line 0)
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.fn')
    (anonymous function) (bootstrap.min.js, line 11)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (slide3.jpg, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (GoodDog-webfont.woff, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (GoodDog-webfont.ttf, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (GoodDog-webfont.svg, line 0)
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.flexslider').flexslider()')
    (anonymous function) (Project, line 24)
    dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js, line 3)
    handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js, line 3)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (favicon.ico, line 0)
```